# why divide norm of w in svm

Tags: machine-learning, svm

So I get this through the math behind the SVM (Support Vector Machine), and I get this formula

$$(w^T)(x_1-x_2) = 2.$$

We then divide both side with norm of $w$ then we get the new formula

$$ \frac{w^T}{\|w\|}(x_1-x_2) = \frac2{\|w\|}. $$

Why do we divide by the norm of $w$ in both sides?

Comment: You got a certain formula and then divided by $\|w\|$. Then you ask, why did I divide by $\|w\|$? You are the one who divided by $\|w\|$, so only you can answer.

Comment: Presumably, the answer is that the vector $w/\|w\|$ has unit norm.

Comment: Please provide more background and context.